# C# ASP.NET Selecting multiple column from same mysql command and use them in code behind

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, associative-array

I woul make this thing:

```
"select nome,cognome from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice"
```

and then use the value in "nome" and the value in "cognome" in code behind. With PHP there are associative array, in C# ASP.NET?
'till now I have always used two different commands, but now it's annoying.
example:

```
MySqlCommand getNome = new MySqlCommand("select Nome from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice", userConnection);
    MySqlCommand getCognome = new MySqlCommand("select Cognome from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice", userConnection);
    MySqlCommand getEmail = new MySqlCommand("select IndirizzoEmail from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice", userConnection);
    getNome.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codice", codice);
    getCognome.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codice", codice);
    getEmail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codice", codice);
    userConnection.Open();
    string nome = Convert.ToString(getNome.ExecuteScalar());
    string cognome = Convert.ToString(getCognome.ExecuteScalar());
    string email = Convert.ToString(getEmail.ExecuteScalar());
```

Can you help me?
Thanks before,
Daniele

Comment: can you give us a sample of what you are using now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple usage:

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString))
{
   var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "select nome,cognome from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codice", value);
   var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while(reader.Read())
   {
       // here could be problems if database value is null
       var nome = reader["nome"];
       var cognome = reader["cognome"];
   }
}
```

Comment: Could be a problem also if I put "if(reader["nome"]!=null)" ?

Comment: Thanks, now I'm trying it!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this :

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString))
{
   var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "select nome,cognome from Utenti where CodiceCliente = @codice";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codice", value);
   var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if(reader.HasRows) {
   while(reader.Read())
   {

       var nome = reader[0];
       var cognome = reader[1];
   }
reader.Close();
}
}
```

You must check if the `DataReader` has rows to avoid exception and finally don't forget to close it